# XBRL label names differ between instance and calculation documents

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xbrl

I have what is, probably, a very stupid question, but I'm stumped by it and would appreciate any help.
I'm trying to gather xbrl data from SEC filings using Python and BeautifulSoup. One problem I'm having is that certain line items are referred to differently in the instance document and the calculation linkbase.
As a concrete example, take this recent 10-K from PHI Group Inc.:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/704172/000149315221015100/0001493152-21-015100-index.htm
A line item with the xbrl tag '`WriteoffOfFinancingCosts`' shows up as
`<PHIL:WriteoffOfFinancingCosts ...>` in the instance document (along with a value and contexts)
but shows up as '`loc_PHILWriteoffOfFinancingCosts`' in the calculation linkbase.
But this relationship, '`PHIL:`' = '`loc_PHIL`', isn't standard across XBRL filings. How does one know what prefix will be added to a tag in the calculation linkbase so that (with the prefix removed) it can be reliably tied back to a tag in the instance document?
I can think of various workarounds, but it just seems silly; isn't there somewhere I can look in the calculation linkbase or elsewhere that will just TELL me exactly what prefix is added?
As some (possibly relevant) nuance: lots of tags in lots of filings, of course, have a prefix like 'us-gaap', indicating the us-gaap namespace, but that doesn't seem to guarantee that a tag in the calculation linkbase will therefore look like '`us-gaapAccountsPayableCurrent`' and not '`loc_us-gaapAccountsPayableCurrent`' or '`us-gaap:AccountsPayableCurrent`' or some other variation of the basic pattern, all of which, of course, look different to BeautifulSoup.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please do not close this question! This is an interesting issue that I am sure other users trying to use XBRL programmatically are facing. I would appreciate if you would keep it open for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PHIL:WriteoffOfFinancingCosts` is the name of the XBRL concept, while `loc_PHILWriteoffOfFinancingCosts` is the (calculation linkbase) label of the locator pointing to the concept `PHIL:WriteoffOfFinancingCosts`. This mechanism is the way linkbases connect concepts together: each locator is a "proxy" to a concept.

`loc_PHILWriteoffOfFinancingCosts` is thus an internal detail of the calculation linkbase. The names of linkbase labels are in principle "free to choose", however there are conventions that established themselves (such as prefixing with `loc_`) but I would not rely on them. Rather, you can "follow the trail" by looking at the definition of the linkbase label:

```
<link:loc xlink:type="locator"
          xlink:href="phil-20200630.xsd#PHIL_WriteoffOfFinancingCosts"
          xlink:label="loc_PHILWriteoffOfFinancingCosts" />
```

Where you see, thanks to the `xlink:href` attribute, that this locator points to the concept with the ID `PHIL_WriteoffOfFinancingCosts` in file `phil-20200630.xsd`.

```
<element id="PHIL_WriteoffOfFinancingCosts"
         name="WriteoffOfFinancingCosts" .../>
```

And you can see that the local name of this concept is `WriteoffOfFinancingCosts`. It is in the namespace commonly associated with prefix `PHIL:` but never appears in a concept definition as all concepts in that file are in the namespace commonly associated with `PHIL:`. Now, how do we know this? because at the top of the xsd file, it says `targetNamespace="http://phiglobal.com/20200630"` and the prefix `PHIL:` is also attached to this namespace in the instance file `phil-20200630.xml` with `xmlns:PHIL="http://phiglobal.com/20200630"`

It is common practice to choose concept IDs with the prefix followed by underscore followed by the local name. Some users rely on it, but following the levels of indirection, in spite of being more complex, is "safer": linkbase label `loc_PHILWriteoffOfFinancingCosts` -> concept ID `PHIL_WriteoffOfFinancingCosts` -> concept local name `WriteoffOfFinancingCosts` -> concept's fully qualified name `PHIL:WriteoffOfFinancingCosts`.

You probably notice how complex this is. In fact, this is the reason why it is worth using an XBRL processor, which will do all of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

@Ghislain Fourny: Many thanks. I'm glad to know that I wasn't crazy for finding the situation complex. Knowing now that the linkbase labels are "free-to-choose", here is the specific BeautifulSoup workaround that I've come up with, in case anyone is interested:

```
labeldict = {}
resp = requests.get(calcurl, headers = headers)
ctext = resp.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(ctext, 'lxml')
tags = soup.find_all()
for tag in tags:
    if tag.name == 'link:loc':
        if tag.has_attr('xlink:href') and tag.has_attr('xlink:label'):
            href = tag['xlink:href']
            firstsplit = href.split('#')[1] ## gets the part of the link after the pound symbol
            value = firstsplit.split('_')[1] ## gets the part after the underscore
            key = tag['xlink:label']
            labeldict[key] = value
```

Which results in a dictionary where keys are the 'loc_Phil'-type label names and the values are the plain concept names, e.g. `labeldict['loc_PHILWriteoffOfFinancingCosts'] = 'WriteoffOfFinancingCosts'`
This assumes that xsd links will always follow a format of '...#..._concept'. I haven't found any that don't follow that format, but that's not a guarantee.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't recommend this approach.  The `loc_<elementname>` is structure is very much a convention, as is the `prefix_<elementname>` used for IDs.  I've certainly seen documents that do not follow this convention.  Further, you're hard coding namespaces prefixes (e.g. the `xlink` in `xlink:href`) which are not guaranteed to be the same in all documents.  As per the previous answer, I'd strongly recommend using an XBRL Processor, or at the very least, a fully namespace aware XML processor which Beautiful Soup is not.